# What is Tír Jovincon in Celtic Mythology?

Tags: celtic, afterlife

In a song by Eluveitie, called "Black Water Dawn", we hear about a voyage across the sea, a journey to the Otherworld. At the end of the song the place Tír Jovincon is mentioned. The question is what exactly is this place?

The song describes it just vaguely as a place with "green hills", a "silver stream" and a "newborn sky". The last song lines are: "Can you not see the sun of the dawn / You are so near Tír Jovincon".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Tìr* in Gaelic means "land". *Jovincon* doesn't appear in the Gaelic dictionary. The Gaelic names for the Otherworld are either *Tír na nÓg* (Land of the Young) or *Tír na hÓige* (Land of Youth).

The otherworld is a place where one goes after death in Celtic mythology. They usually cross the sea to get to the other side. So, dying is actually a dangerous journey among the deathly waves covering the cursed depths.

The story of Oisin

> Long ago, people in Ireland believed that there was a beautiful land
>   in the western sea called Tír na nÓg - The land of the young. It was a
>   place where the trees were always green, the flowers were always in
>   bloom and men and women never grew old. This is the story of how
>   Oisín, the son of Fionn MacCumhail leader of the Fianna, came to go to
>   Tír na n-óg.
>
> One morning the Fianna were hunting deer on the shores of Lough Leane
>   in County Kerry. As they rested on a hilltop, a beautiful girl came
>   riding towards them on a snow white horse. She was dressed like a
>   princess and her long golden hair hung to her waist.
>
> As she drew near, Fionn called out “What is your name and what land
>   have you come from?” – “I am Niamh of the Golden Hair and my father is
>   King of Tír na nÓg. I have heard of a great warrior named Oisín. I
>   have to come to find him and ask him to return with me to the Land of
>   the Young.”
>
> Fionn was sad, for he feared that if Oisín went with Niamh, he would
>   never see him again. But it was too late, Oisín was already in love
>   with the princess. He accepted Niamh’s invitation and waving goodbye
>   to Fionn and his friends, he jumped onto the horse behind Niamh. Away
>   they galloped into the morning mist.
>
> Over the land and the sea the fairy horse ran, moving as swiftly as a
>   shadow. At last they reached the golden shores of Tír na nÓg. The king
>   and queen welcomed Oisín and held a great feast in his honour. It was
>   a magical land. Oisín hunted and feasted and at night he told stories
>   of Fionn and the Fianna and of their lives in Ireland. Oisín had never
>   felt as happy as he did with Niamh and before long they were married.
>
> Oisín lived in Tír na nÓg for three hundred years, but being so happy,
>   it only seemed like three. Then a great longing came on him to go back
>   to Ireland. Niamh did not want him to go but at last she agreed and
>   gave him the white horse. Niamh warned him “set foot, even once, on
>   the soil of Ireland and you will never return to Tír na nÓg.”
>
> When Oisín reached Ireland he found that everything had changed. There
>   was no trace of his father or the fianna. As he passed through Gleann
>   na Smol, the valley of the thrushes, he saw a group of men trying to
>   move a large stone. “I will help you” he said. The mighty Oisín
>   stooped down in his saddle, and with one hand, lifted the stone. But
>   as he did so, the saddle strap broke and he tumble to the ground.
>   Immediately the fairy horse galloped away and a great change came over
>   Oisín. In the blink of an eye the great hero of the Fianna became a
>   withered old man.

Comment: Thank you. This leads to the conclusion that Tír Jovincon is a creation of the songwriters, maybe they meant to propose an alternative version of Tír na nÓg? The song is not stating any more details, it's rather cryptic in that respect.

Comment: There are many Gaelic dialects, I wouldn't rule out that Jovincon is used in one or more of those dialects, but I wasn't able to find it in several dictionaries.

Comment: I understand, thank you.

Comment: Jovincon is almost certainly the genitive plural of the Gaulish equivalent of Irish *óg*, young.  Something like Tiros Iouinkon. Both derive from Old Celtic *tíros & *yowankos (cf. Latin terra & iuuencus).

Answer (score 0):

Tír in irish means land
Vin in Italian Latin means wine cón in irish is truncated from Latin meaning shortened or Conchubhar , or conbhrú

late Middle English originally Scots, as a verb in the senses ‘convey’, ‘conduct’, and ‘act as escort

jovialité in French Heartitness

joviale , cheerful hearty

jeunesse, Youth

Von we vae go

escorted Land Of youth and wine

javaneg in Breton means island or land or referred to Javanese which is a language of Java Indonesia

Alot Of others mean French jestraouiñ in Breton means to express emotions or movement which is similar to  joviale or

jeunesse meaning youth in French you can see similarities in Jestraouiñ with Jeunesse

Tir in Welsh is also land so Tír in Celtic languages as a whole so Tír Jovincon is Celtic languages based with Latin based words that Translate to

escorted Land Of youth and wine
Gauls spoke Latin too they knew most of Romance Latin

So escorted Land Of youth and wine or Land Of Youth & wine of can be o from Welsh